# Why do uppercase commands work in my Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, osx

I'm using Bash 3.2.57 on OSX.

Discovered today by accident that I can enter `cp` or `CP` for copy, `ls` or `LS` to list files, and `rm` or `RM` to delete. `CD` to change directory doesn't work. (presumably because `cd` is a builtin).

`man CP`, `man RM` etc don't work

`which CP` points me to `/bin/CP`, but there is no `CP` in my listing of `/bin`.

But `file /bin/CP` shows `/bin/CP: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`.

All very confusing!

Comment: The HFS+ file system used by macOS is case-insensitive. A heritage from the pre-Unix times.

Comment: A HFS+ volume can also be formatted as case-sensitive, but the default for the macOS root partition is case-insensitive (but case-preserving).

Answer (score 3):

The case-insensitive and case-preserving behavior is an old choice made by Apple, and it seems to me that the shell is just echoing whatever you type. (Try `LS /BIN/CP`.)  This behavior is eliminated, finally and quite thankfully, with the introduction of [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System), Apple Filesystem, which  should be available sometime this Fall with the upcoming macOS High Sierra. It will also be on watchOS, tvOS, iOS. Although HFS+ can be formatted as case-sensitive, not all software can distinguish the difference.